# How to prevent Developer conole in Electorn Ap

Tags: ionic2, electron

I am currently developing an Ionic2+Electron App.

I created the ionic app & successfully created .exe using Electron.

My problem is whenver I double click on .exe file chrome developer console also open along with app. How can I disable chrome developer console??

This is my electron.js file

```
//http://blog.thecodecampus.de/setup-ionic-2-electron-typescript-angular2/
'use strict';
const electron = require('electron');
// Module to control application life.
const {
    app
} = electron;
// Module to create native browser window.
const {
    BrowserWindow
} = electron;

let win;

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    });

    var url = 'http://localhost:8100';
    var Args = process.argv.slice(2);
    Args.forEach(function (val) {
        if (val === "dist") {
            url = 'file://' + __dirname + '/www/index.html'
        }
    });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    win.loadURL(url);

    // Open the DevTools.
    win.webContents.openDevTools();

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    win.on('closed', () => {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        win = null;
    });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete this line

```
win.webContents.openDevTools();
```